# Typo3 - SQL Error 2 when trying to create page content

Tags: sql, typo3, mariadb

I get the following error `2: SQL error: '' ()`, when I try to create page content.
It's Typo3 v4.5.22 and I am using MariaDB 10.3 as database.

Does anyone know something about this problem?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the version of MariaDB.
TYPO3 (any version) works with MariaDB up to version 10.1 of MariaDB.

The problems begin with MariaDB 10.2. For example there is the reserved word `recursive` which is used in TYPO3 as a fieldname in some tables.

Anyway you should update your TYPO3 to a currently supported version.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the TYPO3 4.5 -> t3lib/class.t3lib_db.php to support MariaDB like here in TYPO3 7:
https://forge.typo3.org/attachments/35472?utf8=%E2%9C%93&type=sbs

It works.

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a charm. 
FYI Anyone else using netcup in Germany: This works after the updates they made to MariaDB on the 12.12.2022.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that TYPO3 4.5 supports MariaDB (esp. the newer versions which are incompatible with MySQL 5.0/5.5). After all, TYPO3 4.5 was released in 2011, and support for TYPO3 4.5 was dropped a few years ago already.

MariaDB 10.3 was released in 2017, so I guess it's a high amount to make MariaDB 10.3 compatible with TYPO3 4.5.

I suggest you update TYPO3 to any supported version (currently TYPO3 v8/v9 or ELTS version v6.2/v7), or - if that's not possible - try going with MariaDB 10.2 or lower.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it with MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: Tested it, with MariaDB 10.2, its still not working. Maybe i have to go a bit lower.